# Closure inside another closure is escaping or non-escaping

Tags: swift, closures

```swift
func perform(_ clsr: () -> Void) {
    let anotherClosure = {
        clsr()
    }
}
```

The above code gets compiled but when changing the `anotherClosure` to `var`, the compiler gives the error:

> Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'clsr'

```swift
func perform(_ clsr: () -> Void) {
    var anotherClosure = { // error: Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'clsr'
        clsr()
    }
}
```

Also

```swift
func perform(_ clsr: () -> Void) {
    // now it's let still I get the error
    let anotherClosure = {
        clsr()
    }
    
    anotherClosure() // error: Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'clsr'
}
```

but

```swift
func perform(_ clsr: () -> Void) {
 
    let anotherClosure = {
        clsr()
    }
    
    anotherPerfom(anotherClosure) // Now it's works fine
}

func anotherPerfom(_ clsr: () -> Void){
  clsr()
}
```

What is happening behind the scene here? Can anyone please explain to me?

Comment: Nothing is "happening behind the scene". It's right there in front of you. It's the difference between storage and immediate execution.

Comment: I think the diagnostic is buggy. Just changing the definition of a closure from `let` to `var` shouldn't make it escaping.

Comment: @JeremyP It's not buggy; it knows more than you do. An unreferenced let is simply optimized away. It's as if the method body were empty. The incoming closure parameter is never stored, because it doesn't have to be. But with `var` it has to be genuinely stored; that is an escaping closure.

Answer (score 2):

Things to know:

- Escaping means that a function is *stored* somewhere for later execution. If a function parameter *is* going to be stored for later execution, its function type must be marked as `@escaping`.
- A closure here is an anonymous function body. Closures have the power to *capture* a value defined outside the function. That capturing is a form of storage (which is part of what makes closures incredibly cool and useful).

Okay, so here we go.

---

#### Case 1

```
func perform(_ clsr: () -> Void) {
    let anotherClosure = {
        clsr()
    }
}
```

This initializes an immutable value, `anotherClosure`, without any subsequent reference to it. Thus, from the compiler's point of view, this is pretty much as if `perform` were empty of content. You get a warning that you have an unreferenced `let` but that's all; the compiler doesn't need to think about the *content* of `anotherClosure` because `anotherClosure` is going to be optimized away.

---

#### Case 2

```
func perform(_ clsr: () -> Void) {
    var anotherClosure = {
        clsr()
    }
}
```

Same as before, but now the `let` is a `var`. This means that `anotherClosure` will not be optimized away; it is "real" this time. So `anotherClosure` is initialized by *storing* in it a closure that uses its closure *capturing* power to refer to (and thus capture) the `clsr` parameter.

So you are doing exactly what the error message says: `anotherClosure` is being initialized with an escaping closure (the curly braces) which captures `clsr` which is a non-escaping parameter (because you didn't say `@escaping`). To fix this, you would say

```
func perform(_ clsr: @escaping () -> Void) {
```

---

#### Case 3

```
func perform(_ clsr: () -> Void) {
    let anotherClosure = {
        clsr()
    }
    anotherClosure()
}
```

This is like the first one, with `let`, but now there *is* a subsequent reference to `anotherClosure`, so `anotherClosure` cannot be optimized away. But that means that the situation is exactly the same as the second one (the one with `var`); the compiler has to think about how `anotherClosure` is *storing* a closure (the curly braces) which *captures* the incoming parameter `clsr`, and it comes to exactly the same conclusion as in the previous example, for exactly the same reasons.

---

#### Case 4

And last but not least:

```
func perform(_ clsr: () -> Void) {
    let anotherClosure = {
        clsr()
    }
    anotherPerform(anotherClosure)
}

func anotherPerform(_ clsr: () -> Void) {
    clsr()
}
```

That example is just like the first one — this is a `let` that can be optimized away. If you had said `var` we would be back to the second example, but you didn't. It is exactly as if you had said

```
func perform(_ clsr: () -> Void) {
    anotherPerform({ clsr() })
}

func anotherPerform(_ clsr: () -> Void) {
    clsr()
}
```

Writing it that way, we can see that in fact *no storage* of either `clsr` value takes place; execution of the first `clsr` function is immediate. Thus nothing is escaped and the function type does not have to be declared as `@escaping`.